# Getting data from another file

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the data which is in `<script></script>` tags on hello.html to index.html. How can i do that?

index.html:

```
<head>
<script>
// some codes
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div>
<!-- result will be come here -->
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

hello.html:

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
<script>
document.writeln("hello world");
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

**edit**: i want the "document.writeln("hello world");" part, it must be string.

Comment: You better move the script out to external file then you can have `<script type="text/javascript" src="myfile.js"></script>` in both .html files. Otherwise it's nearly impossible to do what you ask for.

Comment: I agree with Shadow Wizard. @doruk your question is not clear, if you wanna to sent data from one page to another using javascript, use redirect with a query string value.

Comment: An edit has been added to the question. i want the "document.writeln("hello world");" part of script, it must be string.

Answer (score 1):

save the script separately as `myScript.js` and then you can use it in both html files with the script include tag! `<script src="myScript.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Move the script into a new file, such as `script.js`, then add this to both files:

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```